# Ubuntu core 22 recovery mode

Tags: data-recovery, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to get into recovery mode by keeping the '1' pressed on my keyboard while booting.
Also tried to keep hitting '1' key while the system is booting up.

Nothing works.
Tried with 2 different keyboards.

I know the keyboard works with the system as I used it for initial configuration.

Happens on ubuntu core 22.

Comment: Ubuntu desktop: hit ESC once, or hold down SHIFT <- either of those, no 1 or 2 key

Comment: I'm talking about ubuntu core, not ubuntu desktop

Comment: ... and you're sure there is a difference in this regard?